# Powerpoint VBA Shape Animation Timing

Tags: vba, animation, powerpoint, shapes

Im looking for way to apply VBA animation Timing Setting to a Shape like :
Animation to start on click with a delay of some seconds.

I am able to apply animation but not able to find way to change animation timing setting in VBA code

```
With vslide.Shapes("Tile")
    .AnimationSettings.EntryEffect = ppEffectFlyFromLeft
End With
```

Using a VBA

Answer (score 0):

This sub will pause execution of the current procedure for however many seconds you specify:

```
Sub pause(sec As Single)
  Dim t As Single: t = Timer
  Do: DoEvents: Loop While Timer < t + sec
End Sub
```

...used simply like `pause 2.5` for a 2.5 second pause.

This is generally the "safest" way to cause a delay since [`DoEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function) allows execution of background events while waiting for [`Timer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timer-function) to reach it's goal, and therefore won't cause the application to [hang](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/how-to/stop-code-execution).

Comment: IM looking for Powerpoint VBA script. Time delay in animation of powerpoint shapes animation